# Using Fleck Websocket for 10k simultaneous connections

Tags: linux, c#-4.0, mono, websocket

I'm implementing a websocket-secure (wss://) service for an online game where all users will be connected to the service as long they are playing the game, this will use a high number of simultaneous connections, although the traffic won't be a big problem, as the service is used for chat, storage and notifications... not for real-time data synchronization.

I wanted to use Alchemy-Websockets, but it doesn't support TLS (wss://), so I have to look for another service like Fleck (or other).

Alchemy has been tested with high number of simultaneous connections, but I didn't find similar tests for Fleck, so I need to get some real info from users of fleck.

I know that Fleck is non-blocking and uses Async calls, but I need some real info, cuz it might be abusing threads, garbage collector, or any other aspect that won't be visible to lower number of connections.

I will use c# for the client as well, so I don't need neither hybiXX compatibility, nor fallback, I just need scalability and TLS support.

Comment: I develop a WS server connector, supports TLS, and it is asynchronous. I have never tried to run it in Mono, it may be interesting to support it. If you have a chance to try, let me know https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener

Comment: It seems it may work http://mono-project.com/Compatibility

Comment: @vtortola Seems nice, might give it a try, but usually supporting mono requires some work, .net applications don't work on mono by default, most of the times there is something incompatible that needs support.

Comment: I will add mono support to my todo list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a test on a Windows machine with Core2Duo e8400 processor and 4 GB of ram.

The results were not encouraging as it started delaying handshakes after it reached ~1000 connections, i.e. it would take about one minute to accept a new connection.

These results were improved when i used XSockets as it reached 8000 simultaneous connections before the same thing happened.

I tried to test on a Linux VPS with Mono, but i don't have enough experience with Linux administration, and a few system settings related to TCP, etc. needed to change in order to allow high number of concurrent connections, so i could only reach ~1000 on the default settings, after that he app crashed (both Fleck test and XSocket test).

On the other hand, I tested node.js, and it seemed simpler to manage very high number of connections, as node didn't crash when reached the limits of tcp.

All the tests where echo test, the servers send the same message back to the client who sent the message and one random other connected client, and each connected client sends a random ~30 chars text message to the server on a random interval between 0 and 30 seconds.

I know my tests are not generic enough and i encourage anyone to have their own tests instead, but i just wanted to share my experience.

Answer (score 2):

I finally added Mono support to [WebSocketListener](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/).

Check here [how to run WebSocketListener in Mono](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/Mono-support).

10K connections is not little thing. WebSocketListener is asynchronous and it scales well. I have done tests with 10K connections and it should be fine.

My tests shows that WebSocketListener is almost as fast and scalable as the Microsoft one, and performs better than Fleck, Alchemy and others.

Comment: I think it's great that you supported mono but i already went to node.

Answer (score 0):

When we decided to try Fleck, we have implemented a wrapper for Fleck server and implemented a JavaScript client API so that we can send back acknowledgment messages back to the server. We wanted to test the performance of the server - message delivery time, percentage of lost messages etc. The results were pretty impressive for us and currently we are using Fleck in our production environment.

We have 4000 - 5000 concurrent connections during peak hours. On average 40 messages are sent per second. Acknowledged message ratio (acknowledged messages / total sent messages) never drops below 0.994. Average round-trip for messages is around 150 miliseconds (duration between server sending the message and receiving its ack). Finally, we did not have any memory related problems due to Fleck server after its heavy usage.